# How can I separate UNITs in systemd & service

Tags: systemd

I wanna register 3 devices(they are USB CAN) and 1 USB to auto-run as soon as turn on my device with systemd & service in Linux(Ubuntu).

I'm using Jetson nano board of Nvidia with Ubuntu 18.04 ver.

here what I did.

First, Added this scripts to end of rules.d/99-systemd.rules

```
# Socket CAN interface
KERNEL=="ttyACM0", SYMLINK="ttyACM0", TAG+="systemd"
KERNEL=="ttyACM1", SYMLINK="ttyACM1", TAG+="systemd"
KERNEL=="ttyACM2", SYMLINK="ttyACM2", TAG+="systemd"

# DTG interface
KERNEL=="ttyUSB0", SYMLINK="ttyUSB0", TAG+="systemd"
```

like this 
[99-systemd.rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1sm9.png)

Second, I made service file as below.

```
[Unit]
Description= xx Router Running script

BindsTo=dev-ttyACM0.device
BindsTo=dev-ttyACM1.device
BindsTo=dev-ttyACM2.device
BindsTo=dev-ttyUSB0.device

After=dev-ttyACM0.device
After=dev-ttyACM1.device
After=dev-ttyACM2.device
After=dev-ttyUSB0.device

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/sgr-100-nano/xx.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

If I connect all the devices to the Jetson board, then It operate well.
(I can check this not only running .sh file but also with ifconfig)

But If there is any unconnected, then the service is killed.

So I searched in Google to solve this problem.
And I found that using "Wants" instead of "Bindsto" at UNIT section in service file can solve this.
Then It will be operated separately.

But it didn't work. The service file can't set the devices.
I can't see any devices(ex. can0, can1, can2) in the ifconfig.

I know if I separate the service for each one single UNIT, It can be solved.

But I wanna use only one .service file for this.

Answer (score 0):

I found that with 'Wants' instead of 'BindsTo' in .service file as I wrote above. It works!

But it's needed a couple of minutes after turn on the device(Jetson Nano).